# Apache - redirect without changing URL in user's browser

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite

Is there a way to redirect with mod_rewrite without changing the URL in the user's browser?

I saw a solution using `[P]` in the end of `RewriteRule`, but this is not working for me.

What I want:

```
https://my-server.com/propostas/billy.joe
   < ---> internally redirect to
https://my-server.com/subdir/propostas_usuarios/billy.joe
```

What I have:

```
  <LocationMatch "/propostas/(?<username>[^/]+)">
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)(.*) /subdir/propostas_usuarios/%{env:MATCH_USERNAME}
  </LocationMatch>
```

This is what is currently working. But after redirecting, I can see `/subdir/propostas_usuarios` in the new URL.

I have tried to use `[P]` like this:

```
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/hpe/propostas_usuarios/%{env:MATCH_USERNAME} [P]
```

But this gives me this errors:

```
[Fri Dec 11 16:02:57.945091 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 16725:tid 140351293593344] mod_proxy.c(1253): [client 10.0.105.36:52700] AH01143: Running scheme https handler (attempt 0)
[Fri Dec 11 16:02:57.945102 2020] [proxy_ajp:debug] [pid 16725:tid 140351293593344] mod_proxy_ajp.c(744): [client 10.0.105.36:52700] AH00894: declining URL https://my-server.com/subdir/propostas_usuarios/billy.joe
[Fri Dec 11 16:02:57.945124 2020] [proxy_fcgi:debug] [pid 16725:tid 140351293593344] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(1032): [client 10.0.105.36:52700] AH01076: url: https://my-server.com/subdir/propostas_usuarios/billy.joe proxyname: (null) proxyport: 0
[Fri Dec 11 16:02:57.945131 2020] [proxy_fcgi:debug] [pid 16725:tid 140351293593344] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(1035): [client 10.0.105.36:52700] AH01077: declining URL https://my-server.com/subdir/propostas_usuarios/billy.joe
[Fri Dec 11 16:02:57.945149 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 16725:tid 140351293593344] proxy_util.c(2338): AH00942: HTTPS: has acquired connection for (*)
[Fri Dec 11 16:02:57.945159 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 16725:tid 140351293593344] proxy_util.c(2393): [client 10.0.105.36:52700] AH00944: connecting https://my-server.com/subdir/propostas_usuarios/billy.joe to my-server.com:443
[Fri Dec 11 16:02:57.946130 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 16725:tid 140351293593344] proxy_util.c(2616): [client 10.0.105.36:52700] AH00947: connected /subdir/propostas_usuarios/billy.joe to my-server.com:443
[Fri Dec 11 16:02:57.946210 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 16725:tid 140351293593344] proxy_util.c(3085): AH02824: HTTPS: connection established with 10.30.6.52:443 (*)
[Fri Dec 11 16:02:57.946233 2020] [proxy:error] [pid 16725:tid 140351293593344] AH00961: HTTPS: failed to enable ssl support for 10.30.6.52:443 (my-server.com)
[Fri Dec 11 16:02:57.946236 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 16725:tid 140351293593344] proxy_util.c(2353): AH00943: HTTPS: has released connection for (*)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Where exactly are you using this directive? In a _server_ or _virtualhost_ context? "But after redirecting, I can see `/subdir/propostas_usuarios`" - what type of "redirect" was this? 302? 301?

Answer (score 0):

The `P` flag sends the request through mod_proxy - which does not appear to be required here. You simply require an internal rewrite to another subdirectory.

> ```
> <LocationMatch "/propostas/(?<username>[^/]+)">
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)(.*) /subdir/propostas_usuarios/%{env:MATCH_USERNAME}
> </LocationMatch>
> ```

This looks like it should work - there is no external redirect here, as you appear to be observing. However, there is no `L` (oe `END`) flag on the `RewriteRule` directive, so processing will continue and it may be a later directive that triggers the redirect? (Although external redirects should really be *before* any internal rewrites.)

If you also have a `.htaccess` file (or `<Directory>` container) then these directives are also processed later and could potentially trigger a redirect. (?)

This rule can also be "simplified" - there's no need for the `<LocationMatch>` wrapper, as it can all be done in a single `RewriteRule` directive.

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/propostas/([^/]+)$ /subdir/propostas_usuarios/$1 [L]
```

I've put an end-of-string anchor on the regex, otherwise it would match a URL of the form `/propostas/billy.joe/anything`. The `$1` is a backreference to the first captured group (ie. the *username*) in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

As mentioned above, I've included the `L` flag to prevent further directives in the current context being processed. However, directives in `<Directory>` containers (and `.htaccess`) will still be processed.

If you were previously seeing an external redirect then you will need to esnure your browser cache has been cleared before testing.